# Android popupWindow can not show popupWindowA and dismiss popupWindowB at one click

Tags: android, popupwindow

there have two View,and each one set `setOnTouchListener()` to show a popupWindow.when I click viewA the popupWindowA show.when I Click viewB.I want popupWindowA dismiss and popupWindowB show,but there just the popupWindowA dismiss,the popupWindowB do not show.anyone can help me,thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

How did you do in your code? The following is a workable example.

```
    aButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_a);
    bButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_b);

    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (popupWindowB != null && popupWindowB.isShowing()) {
                popupWindowB.dismiss();
            }

            if (popupWindowA == null) {
                popupWindowA = new PopupWindow(v.getContext());
            }
            popupWindowA.setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.popup_a, null));
            popupWindowA.setHeight(100);
            popupWindowA.setWidth(100);
            popupWindowA.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });
    bButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (popupWindowA != null && popupWindowA.isShowing()) {
                popupWindowA.dismiss();
            }

            if (popupWindowB == null) {
                popupWindowB = new PopupWindow(v.getContext());
            }
            popupWindowB.setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(
                    v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popup_b, null));
            popupWindowB.setHeight(150);
            popupWindowB.setWidth(150);
            popupWindowB.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: this way is can not. when popup show,btn can not recieve touch event.

Answer (score 0):

try to use setondismisslistener for the firstpopup and do the things you require in it.